# Is there a shorter way to write this inline if?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, null-check

Hey guys is there a shorter way to write this line.

```
int objectID = jsonObject != null && jsonObject.ObjectID.HasValue && jsonObject.ObjectID.Value > 0 ? jsonObject.ObjectID.Value : defaultObject.ObjectID;

//jsonObject.ObjectID is int?
```

Can u use a null coalesce to check null and > 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this, it takes advantage of [null conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) and *lifted* operators

```
int objectID = jsonObject?.ObjectID > 0 ? jsonObject.ObjectID.Value : defaultObject.ObjectID;
```

<sub>***Note*** : This assumes `defaultObject.ObjectID` is an `int` and not an `int?`</sub>

Comment: @BOT_Billy if this has solved your problem, best mark it as correct to benefit other users. if you have another solution you like, feel free to self answer and mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

```
int objectID = jsonObject?.ObjectID.HasValue && jsonObject.ObjectID.Value > 0 ? jsonObject.ObjectID.Value : defaultObject.ObjectID;
```